# Jetpack compose. Center icon in ListItem

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How to properly center an icon in ListItem?

```
Column {
    ListItem(
        icon = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Delete,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },
        secondaryText = { Text("secondaryText") },
        text = { Text("text") }
    )
    Divider()
}
```

gives this result

[image]

ListItem implementation uses explicit  `Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart)` to place the icon. Mmm...why?

I can, of course, use paddings or create a custom ListItem, but there must be a standard solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**M2 specs**](https://m2.material.io/components/lists#specs), you can add the **`Modifier.size(40.dp)`** to the `Icon`

Something like:

```
    ListItem(
        text = { Text("Two line list item with 40x40 icon") },
        secondaryText = { Text("Secondary text") },
        icon = {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
            )
        }
    )
```

[image]

The `ListItem` follows the [material guidelines](https://material.io/components/lists#specs):

[image]

---

With **M3** it is not needed since the `leadingContent` has a default `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center`:

```
Column {
    ListItem(
        leadingContent = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Delete,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },
        supportingText = { Text("Supporting Text") },
        headlineText = { Text("Headline Text") }
    )
    Divider()
}
```

[image]

[Specs:](https://m3.material.io/components/lists/specs#129ef830-d120-45fe-94b4-a6b4346a87b4)

[image]

Comment: Why 40? Where does this magic number come from?

Comment: @vitidev I've update the answer adding the link to the material documentation.

Comment: I understood. Although, according to your link, in the Content types section there is an example with small icons centered. ListItem turned out to be not very universal, because they could have given the opportunity to center

Comment: You could also add .padding(8.dp) to achive 24dp icon centered